# Has weight 2kg or 2kg weight

Tags: idiomatic-language

I was wondering about variations of the form

"[subject] has/is [property] [units]."

So far, I concluded that these are agreeable as well as:

"[subject] with [property] [units] is..."

"[subject] has a [property] of [units]."

"A [property]-[units] [subject] is..."

---

Below are some examples.

Initially, I was wondering about "field index." Since it's not common, I added "weight," which is supposed to be simple as a technical term. Unfortunately, since there's the verb "weigh", the weight examples sound awkward, where I suggested to use "mass" instead.

Most of example A is incorrect, but I'm leaving it as is not to put the discussion afterwards out of context.

In example B, I used the more common "vertex valence/degree," for which I could find expressions on google.

In example C, I took the simplest form and added different properties to give more examples for the pattern and for future searches.

---

Example A:

1. It has weight of 2kg.
2. It has 2kg weight. (Treating 2kg as an adjective.)
3. It has field index of 2. (Same principle.)
4. It has 2 field index.
5. It has weight 2kg.
6. It has field index 2.

---

Example B:

1. The vertex (in a graph) has valence 2.
2. The vertex has a valence 2.
3. The vertex is 2-valence.
4. A vertex with valence 2.
5. A vertex of degree 2.
6. The vertex has degree 2.
7. A degree 2 vertex.
8. A 2-degree vertex.

---

Example C:

1. It is an update of rank 2.
2. It is a rank-2 update.
3. The vertex has defect (or Gaussian curvature) 90 degrees.
4. A surface of genus 2.

Comment: We just do not normally say: x has a weight of y. In English, we use the **verb**: X weighs Y.

Comment: I updated the parenthetical comment for A.1.

Comment: You shouldn't say as in. You should just use the verb in those examples with weight.

Comment: Okay, so as people said, these examples are wrong or sound weird.

Comment: This is a request for proofreading, and asks multiple questions in one, so it is way off-topic. I'm closing this to new answers.

Comment: @gotube, I disagree. I asked about variations for the pattern, "Subject has property with units", using various examples to make it concrete. There's nothing here related to proofreading. Please, open the question.

Comment: @ZoharLevi The wording of your question is a proofreading request: "*What do you think about these examples.*" If you want to reword your question so it's clearly about one aspect of English, then I'll reopen it. Right now it's more than a dozen similar but separate proof-reading questions. On top of that, as Randomhead pointed out, none of your examples are good, so it doesn't look like you've done any work to find the answer on your own, which is another reason a question can be off-topic

Comment: @gotube, I edited the question. Embracingly, the first examples in A were my initial intuition, and the rest of A are just a sanity check that it's wrong. If you feel that I haven't done research, then please point me to a google reference so I learn for the future.

Comment: @ZoharLevi I think you mean: embarrassingly, don't you? :)

Comment: A classic miss of an "auto-correct" result (by the author).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It has weight of 2kg.** Would be better with "a" before "weight", but acceptable.
**It has 2kg weight.** Would be better with "of" after "2kg", but still would be weird with that.
**It has field index of 2.** Same as A1, but less need for "a".
**It has 2 field index.** Sort of sounds like you're saying its field index has two different values. Would be improved, but still not great, but adding more words, such as "It has 2 as field index".

**The vertex (in a graph) has valence 2.** A bit awkward, but could be idiomatic for some communities (I'm used to the term "degree" rather than "valence").
**The vertex has a valence 2.** No, needs "of" after "valence". 
**The vertex is 2-valence.** Works better as an adjective ("It is a 2-valence vertex") than a subject complement, but can be acceptable.
**A vertex with valence 2.** A bit awkward; at least with "degree", "has" or "of" is more common.
**A vertex of degree 2.** Normal graph theory phrasing.
**The vertex has degree 2.** Normal graph theory phrasing.
**A degree 2 vertex.** Normal graph theory phrasing, but hyphen between "degree" and "2" would improve readability.
**2-degree vertex.** I think it's pretty standard to put the number after the word "degree".

Comment: Your comments on the mistaken phrases would be easier to read if you just wrote them out.

Comment: I don't know how to talk about vertices and valences, but the other suggestions are not acceptable English. Also, what @Lambie said: please write out the correct version so readers don't have to create the sentences in our heads.

Comment: @gotube, can you please be more specific: which suggestions aren't acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

None of your six examples are correct English.

Your examples 2, 4, 5, and 6 are unsalvageable. English does not work that way.

Your examples 1 and 3 would be grammatically correct if you inserted the *indefinite article*: "It has **a** weight of 2kg," "it has **a** field index of 2." (For weight you could also use the *definite article* and make it a comparison: "It has **the** weight of two one-kilo barbells.")

But those still sound unnatural and unidiomatic, at least for weight. Instead:

- It weighs 2kg.
- Its field index is 2.

"Field index" is not a common thing to talk about and so "It has a field index of 2" could work. It definitely sounds more technical and not quite as natural as describing "field index" as a property which the object *possesses*, but it could work. "It has a weight of 2kg" is not something a native speaker would ever say.

Comment: I also wouldn't use weight like that, but I gave it as a comparable example. About your indefinite article suggestion. Aren't both weight and index in these cases uncountable? I added another example with valence.

Comment: _Weight_ in this sense is uncountable, but when you are specifying it with _of_ it requires an article: _a weight of 2kg_.

Comment: "of" is cumbersome; what will it be without "of"?

Comment: Without "of" it will be just as ungrammatical as it was before.

Comment: @ZoharLevi - Without *of* it would be *It weighs 2kg,* as indicated above.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the same rule whether it's weight, mass, degree, field index, or valence. Does it mean that expressions on google, such as "vertex has valence two", are wrong? To confirm, I can say "a weight of 2kg," but "a 2kg weight" is wrong?

Comment: ""Field index" is not a common thing to talk about" Do you mean "It's not something that the general population commonly talks about" or "It's not something mathematicians commonly talk about"? If the latter, you are quite wrong.

Comment: ""It has a weight of 2kg" is not something a native speaker would ever say." I can see a native speaker saying that, especially if it's a container that contains 2kg of weight rather than an object that has an intrinsic weight of 2kg. Certainly "It has a capacity of 2kg" is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

From Pondy.

None of Example A are acceptable to me.  They should be

1. It has a weight of 2kg.
2. Its weight is 2kg
3. It has a field index of 2.
4. Its field index is 2
5. It weighs 2kg.

Example B:

1. The vertex (in a graph) has valence 2.  OK
2. The vertex has a valence 2.   NO: should be The vertex has a valence of 2.
3. The vertex is 2-valence.  WEIRD
4. A vertex with valence 2.  OK
5. A vertex of degree 2. OK
6. The vertex has degree 2.  OK
7. A degree 2 vertex.  WEIRD
8. A 2-degree vertex. NO

Example C:

1. It is an update of rank 2.    OK
2. It is a rank-2 update.  NO.  Shouldn't have the hyphen